# CakePHP global variables in model

Tags: cakephp, model, global

I am making one CakePHP project with Auth component. When I log in I got Session variable with user data. At the moment I am using this variable in controllers to pass data to the model.

```
$user = $this->Session->read('Auth');
$costs = $this->Posts->get_quartal_cost($user, $quartal, TRUE);
```

As I am using this in many controllers/models I am thinking that this is not DRY approach, so I wanted to make it better - something in AppModel(?)

Do you have some advice how to do that better?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the beforeFilter event in your AppController and do something like this:

```
public function beforeFilter()
{
  if ( $this->Session->check('Auth') )
    Configure::write('Auth', $this->Session->read('Auth'));
}
```

From anywhere in your controllers, models and even views, you'll be able to access it by using `echo Configure::read('Auth');`. See the [Configuration class](http://book.cakephp.org/view/42/The-Configuration-Class) documentation for more information.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that Configure class is meant for more "static" data, like configuration, settings, etc.